# How to make Arabic font-stretch: condensed or expanded in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to use Arabic fonts in my website and want the headings condensed but there is not effect in text, But when I use English fonts like Arial then CSS effectively condensed the characters.

Kindly help me making Arabic fonts condensed.

```
.heading{ font-size: 60px; text-align: center; color: maroon; font-weight: bolder; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-stretch: ultra-expanded }

  <div class="heading">هذا ڪتاب</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<html lang="ar">` to your HTML to specify that the language is Arabic. You also need to use the `:lang(ar)` pseudoselector to target Arabic language text. Also, `font-stretch` doesn't work on every font, only some. You can read more about `font-stretch` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch) (MDN) or [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-stretch/) (CSS-Tricks).

For fonts that do not allow `font-stretch`, you can work around it by using positive `letter-spacing` to expand the word, or negative `letter-spacing` to condense the word.

Here's an example stretching the text with `letter-spacing: 30px`:

```css
.heading:lang(ar) { 
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: maroon;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-stretch: ultra-expanded;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ar">
<p class="heading">هذا ڪتاب</p>
```

Here's an example condensing the text with `letter-spacing: -5px`:

```css
.heading:lang(ar) { 
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: maroon;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-stretch: ultra-expanded;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ar">
<p class="heading">هذا ڪتاب</p>
```